# How to transform file_field_tag into a link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload

How do I transform the usual input field tag `<%= file_field_tag :file, multiple: true %>` like [image: normal input field tag]

into a link :

[image: github]

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

HTML:

```
<input type='file' id='file' name='file' />
<a href="#" id='link-upload'>Upload</a>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('#link-upload').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#file').click();
    });
  });
</script>
```

CSS:

```
#file{ width:0; height:0; }
```

Make sure to add jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.write("\<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js' type='text/javascript'>\<\/script>");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

**HTML**

```
<a class="btn-input">seleccionándolos<input type="file" multiple="" id="comment-images" /></a>
```

**CSS**

```
.btn-input {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.btn-input input[type="file"] {
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0.0;
  /* Standard: FF gt 1.5, Opera, Safari */
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  /* IE lt 8 */
  -ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=0)";
  /* IE 8 */
  -khtml-opacity: 0.0;
  /* Safari 1.x */
  -moz-opacity: 0.0;
  /* FF lt 1.5, Netscape */ 
}
```

[Example here](http://embed.plnkr.co/atyuBnVNktl8YSfdfPJT/preview)